# How do you create a specialized version of an existing directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My plan was to create a specialized version of the `ngOptions` directive that goes and fetches a `select`'s options from an external JSON source. My plan was to some inject the `ngOptions` directive (the base) into my directive (the specialization).

```
angular.module('App.directives')
  .directive ("selectDatasource", function ($http, ngOptions) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.dataSource = {};
            attrs.ngOptions = "k as v for (k,v) in dataSource";
            ngOptions.link (scope.element, attrs);
            $http.get(attrs).success(function(r) { scope.dataSource = r; });
        }
    };
});
```

You could then use this as follows:

```
<select name="myOption" select-datasource="http://mysite/datasource"/>
```

However, `ngOptions` fails to inject and I can't see how directives can be injected. I'm not sure this is the best approach anyway. If not, what is a good approach in general terms for specializing one of the built-in directives?

Comment: `link` is too late in the digest to add Angular directives.  Try `compile` or the `$compile` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
app.directive('selectDatasource', ['Loader', function (Loader) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    compile: function (tElement, attr) {
      attr.ngOptions = 'v.value as v.label for v in values';

      return function link(scope) {
        Loader.load(attr.selectDatasource).then(function (response) {
          scope.values = response;
        });
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

though because of the predefined format of `ngOptions` you'd lose a lot of flexibility. Thus it might be better to use something like:

```
app.directive('datasource', ['Loader', function (Loader) {
  return function (scope, element, attr) {
    // add to scope
    scope[attr.datasourceTarget] = [];

    // observer changes
    attr.$observe('datasource', function (nv, ov) {
      if (nv !== ov) {
        Loader.load(nv).then(function (response) {
          scope[attr.datasourceTarget] = response;
        });
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

with:

```
<select
  data-ng-model="test2"
  data-datasource="http://mysite/datasource"
  data-datasource-target="values"
  data-ng-options="v.value as v.label for v in values"
></select>
```

demo:

http://jsbin.com/rukemaha/4/

Comment: Yep, brilliant! Thanks so much for the examples. As @DavidTyron says, `link` is too late to manipulate the template, which seems obvious now. This provides a reliable way for one directive to manipulate another's parameters. Just what I was after.

Comment: One gotcha is don't forget to add the `ng-model`, even if you don't actually need it, otherwise angular won't generate any options!

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove ng-options from select. Instead write new directive that fetches data from external source and sets scope variable, which then is used by the ng-options. Something like this:

```
//template
<select ng-model="myModel.myValue" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in dataSource" select-data-source="http://mysite/datasource/"></select>

//directive
module.directive('selectDataSource', function($http) {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var url = $attrs.selectDataSource;
      $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        $scope.dataSource = response;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I could do that. But that means I've got to always add two directives to every select. It also means `dataSource` isn't encapsulated by the directive.

Comment: You can always wrap select and select-data-source in another directive template, which would compile both of these at once. My example is identical to yours regarding data source encapsulation. Besides, it was not part of the question, so I'm not sure what are you expecting. But of course, one could easily rewrite this to use data source url from some constant value or from scope property. Bottom line is that you can't use `select` without `ngOptions` at compile time unless you rewrite the `select` directive yourself.